# SonarQube. Create custom rule for Java

Tags: java, sonarqube

anyone can help me with this case.

I have the next test file:

```
AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider();
AmazonWebServiceClient client = new AmazonS3Client(provider); // Noncompliant
```

Are there way to extract the particular implementation of interface from the variable *provider* when I explore the arguments of constructor AmazonS3Client? Now I can extract AWSCredentialsProvider for this variable only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's not that explicit, I'm guessing that you are trying to retrieve implementation type used to initialize th `provider`variable, which would be `EnvironmentVariableCredientialsProvider`.

There is currently no easy and straightforward way to achieve this. The best way would be to proceed as follow:

- From the `provider` `IdentifierTree`, use the semantic API to get to the corresponding symbol.
- From the `provider` symbol, jump to the declaration tree (which will be null if the identifier is declared in another file).
- From the `declaration`, and if the tree is a `VariableTree`, look for the initializer expression.
- From the `ExpressionTree`, get the type of the symbol Type, which will give you the implementation type.

That's a first step which should help you to get further. Of course you will next probably need to handle cases where the variable is declared without initializer, and then assigned somewhere else. To retrieve these expressions, look at the symbol usages, instead of declaration, and walk the trees.

Comment: Thanks very much.